# Facebook Graph API: getting started

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Can someone explain to me how to start using the Facebook Graph API efficient? The thing is i created a new app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps but then i got so many questions:

-Do i really need to provide a privacy policy and a terms and conditions URL at this moment? I mean the app is hardly in development.

-Is the app review really that strict? For every permission i ask, i must provide a video to my app using that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just try those things before asking? if the app is "hardly in development", there is no need to think about review yet. you must read the platform policy though.

Comment: I tried to use the API and I'm getting an error that my app haven't been reviewed yet...

Comment: you will have to be more specific then. always include exactly what you are trying to achieve, and add your code and debug info and whatnot. right now, your question is not something we can really answer. because "it depends".